# Proper way to start a shell in single user mode under systemd?

Tags: systemd

What is the equivalent way to start a shell under systemd enabled system?

in sysinit/grub I would simply mount the root filesystem as `rw` and pass `init=/bin/bash` to the kernel, and optionally set it to runlevel 1.

On systemd/bootd system, i have all the options to correctly mount my root (luks, lvm, etc) and I see that it gets mounted to `/sysroot`, but passing `init=/sysroot/bin/bash single` to the kernel then fails on a "Switch Root" step on the boot. Which from the docs should happen just fine before init (and if it happens after, wouldn't my init being a shell pause the flow?)

Comment: I do know about `single`/`emergency` and about `sushell` etc. But The problem I have is with encrypted filesystem drivers which in these test systems hold most passwd files so those standard boot modes won't work. And Yes I also have emergency ways to work around that. But I want a way to collect data from 'final' tests which happens over standard installs from several distros without any of those "backdoors". With sysinit I could do that simply having an edit mode enabled on the bootloader and that is what i'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: Try just `init=/bin/bash`, without the `/sysroot` prefix. Also the `single` parameter is not needed.

Comment: @aviro that is the recommended systemd initrd process https://systemd.io/INITRD_INTERFACE/ also why it must have `/sysroot` prefix. Again, i'm trying to get a shell on most distros (debian, rh, arch, etc) so that have to stay.

Comment: The proper way is to use `systemctl isolate TARGET`, where `TARGET` is an `*.target`-file found in `/lib/systemd/system/` which has the flag `AllowIsolate=yes`. For more info take a look at this older article https://www.systutorials.com/change-systemd-boot-target-linux/ . PS you can also create your own custom targets

Comment: PS with `systemctl set-default TARGET`, you can set a default target to being reached after booting the system

Answer (score 1):

## First solution

From the man pages of [`systemd-debug-generator`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-debug-generator.html):

> If the `systemd.debug_shell`<sup>1</sup> or `rd.systemd.debug_shell`<sup>2</sup> option is
> specified, the debug shell service "`debug-shell.service`" is pulled
> into the boot transaction and a debug shell will be spawned during
> early boot. By default, `/dev/tty9` is used, but a specific tty can also be set, either with or without the `/dev/` prefix. [...]
> `rd.systemd.debug_shell` is honored only by initial RAM disk (initrd)
> while `systemd.debug_shell` is honored only in the main system.

So the first thing you could do is add the following parameters to your kernel command line: `single systemd.debug_shell`. This will start `bash` on `tty9` (the default), and you can move there by pressing the <kbd>F9</kbd> key.

You could specify a different tty in the kernel parameter. For instance, with `systemd.debug_shell=tty1` the shell will appear on the first virtual terminal (instead of the 9<sup>th</sup>), so you won't have to switch.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Notice that in older versions of systemd, `systemd.debug_shell` was actually named `systemd.debug-shell` (notice the hyphen instead of the underscore). To check the specific naming of this parameter on your machine, read the man pages of `systemd-debug-generator` on your machine.</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup>I'll also mention `rd.systemd.debug_shell` (or `rd.systemd.debug-shell`, as the previous comment applies here as well) further in this answer.</sub>

## Second solution

If you want to modify your own solution and make it work, you need to use `init=/bin/bash` and not `init=/sysroot/bin/bash` (explanation will follow).

Also, notice that everything that comes after `init=` will be part of the command. This means that `init=/bin/bash single` will literally try to run the command `/bin/bash single`. So the `init=` parameter should be at the end of the command line.

Regarding `single`, if you change your init in the kernel command line, you don't need to add the `single` parameter at all. This parameter is used by the **host's** actual systemd (as opposed to the initrd's systemd), but if you change the your init to `/bin/bash`, it will run **instead** of the host's `systemd`, so the `single` parameter won't be used at all.

You can use just `single` instead of `init=...` which will start the system in single mode (which the same mode as "rescue"), but depending on your specific systemd's implementation, there's a good chance it will ask for your root's password to get an actual shell.

### Explanation about the second solution

Again, notice the distinction between the `initrd`'s init process, and the **host**'s init process. The `initrd` has it's own init (which is, in your case `systemd`), and when it finishes it runs the **host**'s actually init.

This "init" phase happens **after** the initrd finishes. When `systemd` runs inside `initrd`, that's the exact stage where it switches the root (`/`) to `/sysroot`.

You could see it in the man pages of [`systemctl`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemctl.1.html):

> `switch-root` [*ROOT* [*INIT*]]
>
> Switches to a different root directory and executes a new system
> manager process below it. This is intended for use in the `initrd`, and
> will transition from the initrd's system manager process (a.k.a.
> "`init`" process, PID 1) to the main system manager process which is
> loaded from the actual host root files system. This call takes two
> arguments: the directory that is to become the new root directory, and
> the path to the new system manager binary below it to execute as PID 1.
> If both are omitted or the former is an empty string it defaults to `/sysroot/`.

So it will try to run `/sysroot/bin/bash` **during** the "Switch root" stage, when it switches the root directory **to** `/sysroot` (which includes the actual file system). By that time, `/sysroot` won't exist anymore since it will become the root filesystem - `/`.

### See it yourself

You can debug it and observe it yourself. By adding the `rd.systemd.debug_shell` parameter to the kernel command line, you can get an **initrd** shell at virtual terminal number 9 (<kbd>F9</kbd>) where you could look at the `/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt` log, and you'll see exactly what I mean (notice the second line):

```
[    4.673024] host systemd[1]: Starting Switch Root...
[    4.679521] host systemctl[509]: Failed to switch root: Could not resolve init executable /sysroot/bin/bash: No such file or directory
[    4.679968] host systemd[1]: initrd-switch-root.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
[    4.680097] host systemd[1]: initrd-switch-root.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
[    4.680546] host systemd[1]: Failed to start Switch Root.
```